# How to skip a empty line in text file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a text file as below.

```
  l[0]l[1]l[2]l[3]l[4]l[5]l[6]
-----------------------------------
1| abc is a book and cba too
2| xyz is a pencil and zyx too
3| def is a pen and fed too
4| aaa is
```

Actual file is:

```
 abc is a book and cba too
 xyz is a pencil and zyx too
 def is a pen and fed too
 aaa is
```

I'm using below code to perform operation on this text file:

```
import sys
fr = open("example.txt",'r')
for l in fr:
     if(l[3] is "book" or l[3] is "pencil")
          Then do something
     if(l([3] is "pen")
           Then do something
fr.close()
```

When I'm trying to execute this program I'm getting error like

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "abc.py" line 4 in <module>
if(l[3] is "book" or l[3] is "pencil"):
IndexError: list index error out of range
```

Because as per the above text file in last line(i.e line 4) there is nothing at l[3]

l[0]   l[1]  l[2]  l[3]   l[4]   l[5]   l[6]
 aaa  is

Here in 4th line l[3] is empty.
So my question is how to skip this line when l[3] is empty  ?
Can we campare like below

```
if(l[3] ==""):
     continue
```

Please someone help me here.

Comment: Please format your question so that we can try to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the list length at the beginning of your `for` loop and then `continue` if there is no 3rd element:

`if len(l)< 3:
    continue`

PS. Of course, you have to `l.split()` the line first, otherwise you will access single characters only.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the array of words.

But do note, when you index directly on `l`, you are going at the character level and not the word level as you seem to want to. Also, I'd use `==` instead of `is`.

Do something like this:

```
with open("a.txt", 'r') as fr:
    for l in fr:
        words = l.split()
        if len(words) < 3:
            continue
        if words[3] == "book" or words[3] == "pencil":
            print("Book or pencil")
        elif words[3] == "pen":
            print("Pen")
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `for l in fr` python doesn't return an array but a string for each line, that you have to process in the loop. Using `l.strip().split()` will give you an array of strings, where a string would equal a word.

Then, `is` is meant to compare object type, like `is this line a string ? or an int ?`. So you cannot use it here. Use `==` to compare two objects of the same type.

Edit: some example code

```
import sys
fr = open("example.txt",'r')

for l in fr:
    word = l.strip().split()
    if word[3] == "book" or word[3] == "pencil":
        # Do something
    elif word[3] == "pen":
        # Do something

fr.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Taz8do29 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can count the size of words:

```
with open("example.txt", 'r') as example_file:
    for line in example_file:
        words = line.strip().split()
        if len(words) > 3:  # line has more than three words
            if words[3] in ['book', 'pencil']:
                print("4th word is 'book' or 'pencil'")
            elif words[3] == 'pen':
                print("4th word is 'pen'")
```

The output:

```
4th word is 'book' or 'pencil'
4th word is 'book' or 'pencil'
4th word is 'pen'
```

Comment: @jsbueno Thanks, I improved the snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much Darius :)